# Comma separated values in one column - SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Customer Table
--------------
ID   Name
1   James
2   Peter
```

```
Order Table
---------------
OrderId  CustId
100     1
101     1
102     2
```

How can I write a query that returns something like this

```
ID,Name,ListofOrders
1,James,"100,101"
2,Peter,"102"
```

In Sybase I had a function called LIST which I could use but I dont find a similar function in SQL SERVER

Comment: [Here](http://bradsruminations.blogspot.com/2009/10/making-list-and-checking-it-twice.html) you can find the complex solution along with the explanation.

Comment: Wow that is a complex solution :) Sybase was much better with its LIST  function . wonder why SQL server doesnt have this simple thing

Answer (score 13):

Please try:

```
select ID, [Name],
(select OrderID+',' from OrderTable where CustID=ID
group by OrderID for xml path('')) AS ListOfOrders
From CustomerTable
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a User Defined Function as shown below

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CommaSeperatedOrderIDs](@CustId INT) returns varchar(Max)
AS  
BEGIN   

DECLARE @CommaSeperatedValues VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @CommaSeperatedValues = COALESCE(@CommaSeperatedValues+',' , '') + OrderID
FROM OrderTable WHERE CustId = @CustId
RETURN @CommaSeperatedValues

END
```

And then,

```
select ID, [Name], ([dbo].[CommaSeperatedOrderIDs](ID)) AS ListofOrders
From CustomerTable
```

Answer (score 1):

*Adding full details from Sheikh Haris' [link](http://tejasnshah.wordpress.com/2009/02/28/sql-server-get-column-values-as-comma-seperated-list-using-xml-path-instead-of-udfs-using-sql-coalesce/).*

Given this table:

[image]

To get output like:

[image]

Use the following SQL:

```
SELECT field1,
    Substring(convert(varchar(100),
    (
    SELECT (', ' + field2)
        FROM #test t2
        WHERE t1.field1 = t2.field1
        ORDER BY field1, field2
    FOR XML PATH( '' )
                    )), 3, 1000 )
FROM #test t1
GROUP BY field1
```

*I added a convert function to the substring so that the WIDEMEMO field would be displayed (SQL Server)*

Answer (score 0):

A very simple and handy solution given on the link below.

http://tejasnshah.wordpress.com/2009/02/28/sql-server-get-column-values-as-comma-seperated-list-using-xml-path-instead-of-udfs-using-sql-coalesce/

The SQL query written on that link is in an image ...so i couldn't copy it here.