# How do I avoid character encoding when using "FOR XML PATH"?

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005, encoding, for-xml-path

I'm looking to create a comma-separated list of values from a SQL Server 2005 table, just like in [JanetOhara's question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12435284/1383298).  I'm using a query similar to the one presented in [techdo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12435331/1383298) to the question.

Everything is working, except the list of values is getting XML encoded.  What should be:

```
Sports & Recreation,x >= y
```

Is instead returning as:

```
Sports &amp; Recreation,x &lt;= y
```

Is there a way to disable the XML character encoding when using "FOR XML" in SQL Server?

Answer (score 148, accepted):

You just need to use the right options with `FOR XML`. Here's one approach that avoids encoding:

```sql
USE tempdb;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.x(y nvarchar(255));

INSERT dbo.x SELECT 'Sports & Recreation'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'x >= y'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'blat'
   UNION ALL SELECT '<hooah>';

-- BAD:
SELECT STUFF((SELECT N',' + y
  FROM dbo.x 
  FOR XML PATH(N'')),1, 1, N'');

-- GOOD:
SELECT STUFF((SELECT N',' + y
  FROM dbo.x 
  FOR XML PATH, 
  TYPE).value(N'./text()[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, N'');

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.x;
```

If you are on a newer version of SQL Server (2017+), you can use [`STRING_AGG()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and not worry about XML at all:

```sql
SELECT STRING_AGG(y, N',') FROM dbo.x;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=054eca072742658ca829fcdfbf5983b8) demonstrating all three.

Comment: Adding `type` and `.value('.[1]',nvarchar(max)')` worked perfectly.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: TYPE tells SQL to return actual XML, then you have to "Query" this XML for the value you want this is the ".value('.[1]', nvarchar(max)').

More info here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190025.aspx

Comment: The first character in my string was a '<', this was for some reason omitted after implementing this solution.  I solved that issue by adding a blank space at the beginning of the string.

Comment: @alan I couldn't reproduce that problem. Did you change `',' + y` to something else? The `STUFF` is used to strip off the first character, which should be a leading comma unless you changed the query in other ways.

Comment: Worth noting that I found `value` to be case-sensitive, it wouldn't recognise `VALUE`.

Comment: STRING_AGG is worth a look as an alternative to this.  MS example:

```SELECT town,
  STRING_AGG (email, ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY email ASC) AS emails
  FROM dbo.Employee
  GROUP BY town;```

Comment: @NickAllan However note that "STRING_AGG" Is only for SQL 2017+ which isn't much use to anyone who support older systems, but thanks for the heads up.

Comment: For your example to work need to add ('') to PATH. `SELECT STUFF((SELECT N',' + y
  FROM dbo.x 
  FOR XML PATH(''), 
  TYPE).value(N'./text()[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '');`

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this:

```
-- BAD:
SELECT STUFF((SELECT N',' + y
FROM dbo.x 
FOR XML PATH(N'')),1, 1, N'');

-- GOOD:
SELECT STUFF((SELECT N',' + y
FROM dbo.x 
FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','varchar(max)'),1, 1, N'');
```

Answer (score 0):

See this post on [Creating concatenated delimited string from a SQL result set and avoid character encoding when using “FOR XML PATH”](http://linodh.blogspot.com.au/2014/03/creating-concatenated-delimited-string.html)

An alternate approach would be to rely on concatenation of characters (of course sql is not great with string operations as it is developed to work with set theory)

```sql
USE tempdb;
GO 

CREATE TABLE dbo.x ( y NVARCHAR(255) );
INSERT dbo.x
SELECT 'Sports & Recreation'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'x >= y'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'blat'
UNION ALL
SELECT '<hooah>';

DECLARE @delimitedText varchar(max)
SET @delimitedText=''
SELECT @delimitedText += CASE WHEN LEN(@delimitedText) > 0 THEN +','+ y ELSE y END
FROM dbo.x 

SELECT @delimitedText
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.x;
GO
```