# How can i get sql result column as csv without 'for xml'-clause?

Tags: sql, hsqldb

i want data from table like

```
A B
- -
1 a
2 b
3 b
```

in this result form

```
A   B
--- -
1   a
2,3 b
```

but i use hypersonic in version 1.8 and can't find "for xml"-clause.

Any solutions without "for xml" like [Comma separated values in one column - SQL SERVER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435284/comma-separated-values-in-one-column-sql-server)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  a
,   MAX( CASE seq WHEN 1 THEN (b) ELSE '' END )
  + MAX( CASE seq WHEN 2 THEN (', ' + b) ELSE '' END ) 
  + MAX( CASE seq WHEN 3 THEN (', ' + b) ELSE '' END ) 
  + MAX( CASE seq WHEN 4 THEN (', ..') ELSE '' END )
  AS b
FROM (SELECT 
        t1.a
      , t1.b
      , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t t2 WHERE t1.a = t2.a AND t2.b <= t1.b) AS seq 
      FROM t t1) AS temp
GROUP BY a
```